MongoDB-realm. Getting this error : Cannot write to class UserRecord when no flexible sync subscription has been created.'
I’m using this MongoDB template, which works well for uploading Item objects to MongoDB Cloud. However, I want to upload a new object type, UserRecord. Here's the class definition:

using MongoDB.Bson;
using Realms;
using RealmTodo.Services;

namespace RealmTodo.Models
{
    public partial class UserRecord : IRealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [MapTo("_id")]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

        [MapTo("owner_id")]
        [Required]
        public string OwnerId { get; set; }

        [MapTo("summary")]
        [Required]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        [MapTo("mapName")]
        public string MapName { get; set; }

        [MapTo("trackTime")]
        public string TrackTime { get; set; }


        [MapTo("uploadDate")]
        public string UploadDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsMine => OwnerId == RealmService.CurrentUser.Id;
    }
}

Below is the RealmService code I’m using:
using System.Text.Json;
using Realms;
using Realms.Sync;
using RealmTodo.Models;

namespace RealmTodo.Services
{
    public static class RealmService
    {
        private static bool serviceInitialised;

        private static Realms.Sync.App app;

        private static Realm mainThreadRealm;

        public static User CurrentUser => app.CurrentUser;

        public static string DataExplorerLink;

        public static async Task Init()
        {
            if (serviceInitialised)
            {
                return;
            }

            using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("atlasConfig.json");
            using StreamReader reader = new(fileStream);
            var fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RealmAppConfig>(fileContent,
                new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            var appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration(config.AppId)
            {
                BaseUri = new Uri(config.BaseUrl)
            };

            app = Realms.Sync.App.Create(appConfiguration);

            serviceInitialised = true;

            // If you're getting this app code by cloning the repository at
            // https://github.com/mongodb/template-app-maui-todo, 
            // it does not contain the data explorer link. Download the
            // app template from the Atlas UI to view a link to your data.
            DataExplorerLink = config.DataExplorerLink;
            Console.WriteLine($"To view your data in Atlas, use this link: {DataExplorerLink}");
        }

        public static Realm GetMainThreadRealm()
        {
            return mainThreadRealm ??= GetRealm();
        }

        public static Realm GetRealm()
        {
            var config = new FlexibleSyncConfiguration(app.CurrentUser)
            {
                PopulateInitialSubscriptions = (realm) =>
                {
                    var (query, queryName) = GetQueryForSubscriptionType(realm, SubscriptionType.Mine);
                    realm.Subscriptions.Add(query, new SubscriptionOptions { Name = queryName });
                }
            };

            return Realm.GetInstance(config);
        }

        public static async Task RegisterAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            await app.EmailPasswordAuth.RegisterUserAsync(email, password);
        }

        public static async Task LoginAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            await app.LogInAsync(Credentials.EmailPassword(email, password));

            //This will populate the initial set of subscriptions the first time the realm is opened
            using var realm = GetRealm();
            await realm.Subscriptions.WaitForSynchronizationAsync();
        }

        public static async Task LogoutAsync()
        {
            await app.CurrentUser.LogOutAsync();
            mainThreadRealm?.Dispose();
            mainThreadRealm = null;
        }

        public static async Task SetSubscription(Realm realm, SubscriptionType subType)
        {
            if (GetCurrentSubscriptionType(realm) == subType)
            {
                return;
            }

            realm.Subscriptions.Update(() =>
            {
                realm.Subscriptions.RemoveAll(true);

                var (query, queryName) = GetQueryForSubscriptionType(realm, subType);

                realm.Subscriptions.Add(query, new SubscriptionOptions { Name = queryName });
            });

            //There is no need to wait for synchronization if we are disconnected
            if (realm.SyncSession.ConnectionState != ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                await realm.Subscriptions.WaitForSynchronizationAsync();
            }
        }

        public static SubscriptionType GetCurrentSubscriptionType(Realm realm)
        {
            var activeSubscription = realm.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault();

            return activeSubscription.Name switch
            {
                "all" => SubscriptionType.All,
                "mine" => SubscriptionType.Mine,
                _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown subscription type")
            };
        }

        private static (IQueryable<UserRecord> Query, string Name) GetQueryForSubscriptionType(Realm realm, SubscriptionType subType)
        {
            IQueryable<UserRecord> query = null;
            string queryName = null;

            if (subType == SubscriptionType.Mine)
            {
                query = realm.All<UserRecord>().Where(i => i.OwnerId == CurrentUser.Id);
                queryName = "mine";
            }
            else if (subType == SubscriptionType.All)
            {
                query = realm.All<UserRecord>();
                queryName = "all";
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown subscription type");
            }

            return (query, queryName);
        }
    }

    public enum SubscriptionType
    {
        Mine,
        All,
    }

    public class RealmAppConfig
    {
        public string AppId { get; set; }

        public string BaseUrl { get; set; }


        // If you're getting this app code by cloning the repository at
        // https://github.com/mongodb/template-app-maui-todo, 
        // it does not contain the data explorer link. Download the
        // app template from the Atlas UI to view a link to your data.
        public string DataExplorerLink { get; set; }
    }
}

Issue
When I attempt to upload a UserRecord object, I get this error:
Realms.Exceptions.RealmException: 'Cannot write to class UserRecord when no flexible sync subscription has been created.'
What I’ve Tried
I ensured that Device Sync was properly configured through the MongoDB UI.
The sync model screen in MongoDB Cloud does recognize the UserRecord object.
Here's a screenshot of the sync models:
enter image description here
My Project Repository
Here is the link to my repository based on the original MongoDB template:
https://github.com/t4tomer/RealmTimerExample
What I Expected
I expected UserRecord objects to sync with MongoDB Cloud, just like the Item objects in the template app.
Question:
How can I resolve this error and successfully sync UserRecord objects with MongoDB Cloud? Am I missing any additional steps for configuring flexible sync?
here is the Field Permissionsfor UserRecord object :
enter image description here
Pic of the error : enter image description here
